# Acquire data from Weather API Thingsboard

Tags: api, mqtt, thingsboard

I want to compare the weather data from my weather station with the data from openweathermap.

Here is my idea:

I have my weather station as a device. Whenever it sends data to Thingsboard (via MQTT) a TB-rule activates a TB-plugin that queries weather data from openweathermap. This data is then saved together in the database.

Can a plugin grab data from APIs? I successfully did the weather request with a python script and then sent the data to Thingsboard but I would like to replace this part with a Thingsboard plugin.

Do you guys think that is possible?

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks.